# Unable to set spinner position based on values retrieved from database

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-layout, android-emulator

I am developing an android app in which I have 3 spinners populated from a database called
Department,Practice and Address

I am loading them conditionally i.e, if it is department A load Practice A,B and based on practice A address is set.

Then I am saving these positions in an another database table by getSelectedItemPosition().

Now when I am trying them to 3 variables deptpos,practipos and addrpos.
But when I use setSelection after initializing the spinners it is showing only correct position for department rest of them are not working :(

Here is my code

```
//Initializing the shared preferences variable
    final SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());

    //Loading the database in writable format
    db=mydbhelper.getWritableDatabase();

    //For Medicines Table
    try{
        //For medicines
        Cursor medspin = db.query("medicines", null,"_id="+prefs.getInt("pos",1),null,null,null,null);
        medspin.moveToFirst();
        //Filling the variables to set selemedspintion
        deptpos=medspin.getInt(medspin.getColumnIndex("provider_department"));
        practipos=medspin.getInt(medspin.getColumnIndex("provider_practice"));
        addrpos=medspin.getInt(medspin.getColumnIndex("provider_address"));
        hsname=medspin.getString(medspin.getColumnIndex("healthsystem"));
        medspin.close();
        Toast td=Toast.makeText(this,"Loaded dept is "+deptpos+"Loaded Provider is "+practipos+"Address is "+addrpos,Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        td.show();


    }
    catch(Exception e){
        Log.e("Error","Error",e);
    }




    try{

        //Cursor
        Cursor depcur = db.rawQuery("SELECT _id,department,"+prefs.getString("hsname",null)+ " FROM dept_masterdata WHERE "+prefs.getString("hsname",null)+"=1",null);
        depcur.moveToFirst();
        startManagingCursor(depcur);
        String[] from = new String[]{"department"};
        int[] to = new int[] { android.R.id.text1 };
         // Now creating an array adapter and set it to display using my row
        //Adaptor for Department
        SimpleCursorAdapter deptype =new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, depcur, from, to);
        deptype.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        dep.setAdapter(deptype);


    }
    catch(Exception e){
        Log.e("Error","Error",e);
    }
     //Now determine which department is selected
    //Department
    dep.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent,View view,int pos,long id){
            deptid=dep.getSelectedItemId();


            //Setting the practice spinner based on the department selected
            Cursor pracur = db.rawQuery("SELECT _id,practice,dept_link,hs_id FROM practice_masterdata WHERE dept_link="+deptid+" AND hs_id="+(prefs.getInt("hsid",0)),null);
            pracur.moveToFirst();
            startManagingCursor(pracur);
            String[] from1 = new String[]{"practice"};
            int[] to1 = new int[]{android.R.id.text1};
            SimpleCursorAdapter practype =new SimpleCursorAdapter(view.getContext(),android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, pracur, from1, to1);
            practype.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            pra.setAdapter(practype);
        }
        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
        }
    });
    //Practice
    pra.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent,View view,int pos,long id){

            practid=pra.getSelectedItemId();


            //Setting the address  based on the practice selected
            Cursor addcur =db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM address_masterdata WHERE practice_link="+practid,null);
            addcur.moveToFirst();
            startManagingCursor(addcur);
            String[] from2 = new String[]{"address"};
            int[] to2   = new int[]{android.R.id.text1};
            SimpleCursorAdapter addtype =new SimpleCursorAdapter(view.getContext(),android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,addcur, from2, to2);
            addtype.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            add.setAdapter(addtype);
        }
        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
        }
    });
    //Address
    add.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent,View view,int pos,long id){
            addrid=add.getSelectedItemId();


        }
        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
        }
    });







    //Setting the spinners based on the above variables

    dep.setSelection(deptpos);
    pra.setSelection(practipos);
    add.setSelection(addrpos,false);

}
```

I confirmed with a toast if the variables are loading correct values. They are but it is simply not setting them :(. The strange thing is department is showing the correct setting while both practice and address are not all :(. Please kindly point out where I am going wrong

thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does `practice` and `address` have values already? If not then load data for practice and address out of depot selected listener, with by default d first as selected element.

```
depots[] = loadDepots();
depotsSpinner.setAdapter();
depotsSpinner.setSelected(0);

practice[] = loadPractice(depots[0]);
practiceSpinner.setAdapter();
practiceSpinner.setSelected(0);

address[] = loadAddress(depots[0], practice[0]);
addressSpinner.setAdapter();
addressSpinner.setSelected(0);
```